# I'm getting the rosgraph not found error

Tags: ros, rosgraph

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm trying to control a robot that has ROS controllers with a Python program, but everytime I run the program, I get an error regarding the rosgraph library not being found. I've tried everything other people have said in other threads, but nothing has worked so far. This is the program I'm using to try and control the robot:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import rospy, math
import numpy as np
import sys, termios, tty, select, os
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist


class KeyTeleop(object):
    cmd_bindings = {'q': np.array([1, 1]),
                    'w': np.array([1, 0]),
                    'e': np.array([1, -1]),
                    'a': np.array([0, 1]),
                    'd': np.array([0, -1]),
                    'z': np.array([-1, -1]),
                    'x': np.array([-1, 0]),
                    'c': np.array([-1, 1])
                    }
    set_bindings = {'t': np.array([1, 1]),
                    'b': np.array([-1, -1]),
                    'y': np.array([1, 0]),
                    'n': np.array([-1, 0]),
                    'u': np.array([0, 1]),
                    'm': np.array([0, -1])
                    }

    def init(self):
        # Save terminal settings
        self.settings = termios.tcgetattr(sys.stdin)
        # Initial values
        self.inc_ratio = 0.1
        self.speed = np.array([0.5, 1.0])
        self.command = np.array([0, 0])
        self.update_rate = 10  # Hz
        self.alive = True
        # Setup publisher
        self.pub_twist = rospy.Publisher('/cmd_vel', Twist)

    def fini(self):
        # Restore terminal settings
        termios.tcsetattr(sys.stdin, termios.TCSADRAIN, self.settings)

    def run(self):
        try:
            self.init()
            self.print_usage()
            r = rospy.Rate(self.update_rate)  # Hz
            while not rospy.is_shutdown():
                ch = self.get_key()
                self.process_key(ch)
                self.update()
                r.sleep()
        except rospy.exceptions.ROSInterruptException:
            pass
        finally:
            self.fini()

    def print_usage(self):
        msg = """
    Keyboard Teleop that Publish to /cmd_vel (geometry_msgs/Twist)
    Copyright (C) 2013
    Released under BSD License
    --------------------------------------------------
    H:       Print this menu
    Moving around:
      Q   W   E
      A   S   D
      Z   X   Z
    T/B :   increase/decrease max speeds 10%
    Y/N :   increase/decrease only linear speed 10%
    U/M :   increase/decrease only angular speed 10%
    anything else : stop

    G :   Quit
    --------------------------------------------------
    """
        self.loginfo(msg)
        self.show_status()

    # Used to print items to screen, while terminal is in funky mode
    def loginfo(self, str):
        termios.tcsetattr(sys.stdin, termios.TCSADRAIN, self.settings)
        print(str)
        tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())

    # Used to print teleop status
    def show_status(self):
        msg = 'Status:\tlinear %.2f\tangular %.2f' % (self.speed[0], self.speed[1])
        self.loginfo(msg)

    # For everything that can't be a binding, use if/elif instead
    def process_key(self, ch):
        if ch == 'h':
            self.print_usage()
        elif ch in self.cmd_bindings.keys():
            self.command = self.cmd_bindings[ch]
        elif ch in self.set_bindings.keys():
            self.speed = self.speed * (1 + self.set_bindings[ch] * self.inc_ratio)
            self.show_status()
        elif ch == 'g':
            self.loginfo('Quitting')
            # Stop the robot
            twist = Twist()
            self.pub_twist.publish(twist)
            rospy.signal_shutdown('Shutdown')
        else:
            self.command = np.array([0, 0])

    def update(self):
        if rospy.is_shutdown():
            return
        twist = Twist()
        cmd = self.speed * self.command
        twist.linear.x = cmd[0]
        twist.angular.z = cmd[1]
        self.pub_twist.publish(twist)

    # Get input from the terminal
    def get_key(self):
        tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
        select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0)
        key = sys.stdin.read(1)
        return key.lower()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('keyboard_teleop')
    teleop = KeyTeleop()
    teleop.run()
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

EDIT:

Hello ahendrix. This is the erroe we're getting:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 "/home/pgr/pruebas-concepto-simulacion-cv/ENTREGA-PGR2/Gazebo - Ros - OpenCV/SRC/MoverRobot.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pgr/pruebas-concepto-simulacion-cv/ENTREGA-PGR2/Gazebo - Ros - OpenCV/SRC/MoverRobot.py", line 126, in <module>
    rospy.init_node('keyboard_teleop')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/client.py", line 306, in init_node
    rospy.core.configure_logging(resolved_node_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/core.py", line 235, in configure_logging
    _log_filename = rosgraph.roslogging.configure_logging('rospy', level, filename=filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosgraph/roslogging.py", line 105, in configure_logging
    rosgraph_d = rospkg.RosPack().get_path('rosgraph')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 203, in get_path
    raise ResourceNotFound(name, ros_paths=self._ros_paths)
rospkg.common.ResourceNotFound: rosgraph
```

Likewise, these are the links we looked to try and fix the error:

http://answers.ros.org/question/58437/rospkgcommonresourcenotfound-catkin/

http://answers.ros.org/question/243478/getting-rosgraph-resource-not-found-when-trying-to-get-turtlebot-local_plan/

http://answers.ros.org/question/37826/lauch-problems-resourcenotfound/

Thank you so much for your attention ahendrix and we hope you can help us. :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261992/i%27m-getting-the-rosgraph-not-found-error/) by [diegovargas34](https://answers.ros.org/users/30439/diegovargas34/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-05-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-05-17**:
Please include the full text of the error message in your question, and links to the other questions that you've tried (and any debug information those questions may have recommended)

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-05-17**:
It *seems* like this is just a case of your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH being set incorrectly, but if you listed the steps that you've already tried it would be easier to give useful advice.

**Comment by [diegovargas34](https://answers.ros.org/users/30439/diegovargas34/) on 2017-05-18**:
Hello @ahendrix We've edited the post with the information you asked. Thank you so much.

**Comment by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on 2017-05-18**:
Does `rospack find rosgraph` result in anthing?

**Comment by [diegovargas34](https://answers.ros.org/users/30439/diegovargas34/) on 2017-05-18**:
It results in an error with a file called librospack. It says it can't open the libraries because the file or directory doesn't exists.

**Comment by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on 2017-05-18**:
Interesting. Normally, if a package doesn't exist it simply says "not found'. Like @ahendrix suggested it's probably something to do with the path. Can you type `printenv | grep ROS` and edit the question with the result.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-19**:
Could you also tell us what sort of system this is, Linux distro & version you are running, version of ROS and how you installed that.

**Comment by [diegovargas34](https://answers.ros.org/users/30439/diegovargas34/) on 2017-05-22**:
I'm so sorry guys for answering so late. This is the exact error when we execute rospack find rosgraph:

rospack: error while loading shared libraries: librospack.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

**Comment by [diegovargas34](https://answers.ros.org/users/30439/diegovargas34/) on 2017-05-22**:
And printenv | grep ROS shows the following:

ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/indigo

ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/indigo/share

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://mia:11311/

which is weird because I had to change the ROS_MASTER_URI variable to http://localhost:11311/ in order for the model to run.

**Comment by [diegovargas34](https://answers.ros.org/users/30439/diegovargas34/) on 2017-05-22**:
Also, @gvdhoorn , I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. As for the version of ROS, I get  when I run rosversion ros, and  when I run rosversion -d, which I don't understand, because I was able to install ROS directly with the command provided in the official page of ROS.

**Comment by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on 2017-05-22**:
Try rosversion <package_name>, like `rosversion roscpp`. That should work since roscpp should be in your current path. But your workspace isn't within your path. Have you actually made a catkin workspace, or is this a bare python program that you're trying to run?

**Comment by [diegovargas34](https://answers.ros.org/users/30439/diegovargas34/) on 2017-05-22**:
rosversion roscpp shows 1.11.21 I have made a catkin workspace in the folder of the model and I'm trying to run the python program in another directory.

**Comment by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on 2017-05-22**:
Type `python` into a terminal. Then, in the python interpreter, type `import rospy`, then type `rospy.init_node('hello')`. Can you confirm this gives the same rosgraph error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your error message does not include a listing of the entries in the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH (normally these would be `ROS path [0]`, `ROS path [1]`, etc). Presumably this means that your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH is not set at all.

It looks like you need to source the `setup.bash` or `setup.sh` for your workspace, which will set up your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH and the other environment variables that ROS needs.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0